# merging 2 columns followed by making a new column in a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I want to ask, how can I make a new column in a data.frame  in R by merging 2 columns (with categorical values) with all rows in the file. Following example is showing alternate categorical conditions in `column_1` and `column_2` how could I make `column_3` by merging `columns_1` and `column_2`? Moreover, in 4th row both columns have values, so in this case what would be in `column_3`. (`NA` are blanks).

```
Column_1 Column_2  Column_3
1          NA
NA          2
2           NA
NA          1
1           2
```

Comment: `dplyr::coalesce(df$Column_1, df$Column_2)`, or reverse the order if you want `Column_2` to take precedence

Comment: *You* have to decide what to do if both columns have values.

Comment: What do you mean by merging? Just have both values in sequence or adding up?

Comment: Don't attach your data as an image. It makes the question harder to read and is not reproducible [I've rolled it back].

Comment: Ok. Thanks for telling solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider providing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier for us to help you.
E.g.

```
df <- data.frame(Column_1 = c(1, NA, 2, NA, 1), Column_2=c(NA, 2, NA, 1, 2))
```

You could use `ifelse` here if you just wanted to stick to base R.

```
df$Column_3 = ifelse(is.na(df$Column_1), df$Column_2,
                     ifelse(is.na(df$Column_2), df$Column_1,
                            df$Column_1))
```

This says "if Column 1 is NA, use column 2. Otherwise, if Column 2 is NA, use column 1. Otherwise (both are not NA), use Column 1".

You need to decide what you want to do if both columns are not-NA.

If you want to skip some typing (of `df$`) you can use `with`

```
df$Column_3 = with(df,
                   ifelse(is.na(Column_1), Column_2,
                          ifelse(is.na(Column_2), Column_1,
                                 Column_1)))
```

Comment: Thank you, It helped me out.